# C# : Excel : Determine if a string is a valid Range reference?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel-interop, vb.net-to-c#

How would this VB function will look like as C# ? The goal is to determine if a string `ref` represents a valid datasheet `Excel.Range`. This isn't a trivial VB to C# conversion as Range can't be constructed.

```vb
Private Function IsRange(ref) As Boolean
'   Returns True if ref is a Range
    Dim x As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set x = Range(ref)
    If Err = 0 Then IsRange = True Else IsRange = False
End Function
```

Best

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/

Comment: :) @Sylca unfortuantely not so easy.

Comment: Hoped it would help you.:-) Nothing is easy these days my friend. Best:-)

Comment: @Sylca : nope, it doesnt. As I meant unfortunately it doesnt help.

Comment: @HeinrichStack are you sure that your example source is VB.NET? Constructing a `Range` like that doesn't seem to be valid for VB.NET. Perhaps it is VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I would have liked to find a way to not have to rely on an exception for checking the validity of a cell reference. But I couldn't not find a way to directly test for it.

So instead I am using the OP's approach. The problem is that `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` is an interface and can't be directly created. Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609981/262789) the solution is to use the `get_Range` method from `_Application` or `Sheet`.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application ExcelApp;

private bool IsRange(string refr) {
   try {
      var unused = ExcelApp.Range[cellReference, Type.Missing];

      return true;
   }
   catch {
      return false;
   }
}
```