# Check if String is excel format c#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, clipboard

My program allows me to paste an excel that was copyed and add to a listview. I would like to know how I can check if the String is really a copy from a excel file.I found this solution([c# : Excel : Determine if a string is a valid datasheet Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871480/c-sharp-excel-determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-datasheet-range)) but its not working.

```
 String cp = Clipboard.GetText();
 string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
 string[] rows = cp.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
 for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length - 1; i++){
    ListViewItem tempT = new ListViewItem(rows[i].Split('\t'));
    listView.Items.Add(tempT);
 }
```

The solution in the link above suggests this function:

```
private bool IsRange(string refr) {
   try {
      Range(refr);
      return true;   // if no error occurred, refr is a valid range
   }
   catch {
      return false;   // not a valid range
   }
}
```

The erro says:

```
 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

Comment: A `Range()` needs a sheet reference, i.e. `asheet.Range()`

Comment: How do I create the variable asheet?I tried `WorksheetClass asheet` but its not working.

Comment: IIRC you need a *real* sheet and hence a real workbook. I would look for an alternate method.

Comment: I tried using `Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)` and it worked even if the string has "\t" instead of comma.